# How best to split a stereo audio source (LR) to two stereo amps (LL+RR)?

Tags: audio, stereo

Suppose one has a stereo audio source with a single 3.5mm stereo output jack, and one wants to split the left and right channels so that each is produced on one of two powered (i.e. self-amplified) stereo speakers, each of which has a single 3.5mm stereo input jack — the intention being for each of the two stereo speakers to play its assigned mono channel on both of its own output channels, as if the input were balanced mono. Symbolically, this might be represented as {LR}→{LL+RR}. What would be the most straightforward way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I guess you could use a TRS->2×TS adapter followed by a pair of TS->2×TS splitters?

Comment: Why not use a splitter with {LR+LR}?  Splitter = 1 to 2 way adapter or a "ménage à trois" connector

Comment: @Felthry ...further followed by a pair of 2×TS→TRS adapters? Argh, I was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: If you need them in TRS connectors, then, yes. But if you want to do some wiring of your own, you should be able to get a couple TRS jacks and cross some wires between them.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt Because that would defeat the purpose of having a stereo source to begin with. The objective is to position the two stereo amps at a distance from each other so as to maintain stereo separation of the original signal.

Comment: but you still  have stereo from each amp, but now I see you want a greater distance.

Comment: I realize this is a pretty rudimentary question in terms of "[electronics.se]", but this forum seemed slightly more germane than [sound.se], so I posted here.

Answer (score 2):

For line-level audio (or approximately-line-level as in "headphone jacks") connections you can just split an output with wires and connect it to multiple inputs. To achieve any particular audio channel mapping you would like, you only need to make the corresponding connections between the TRS connectors' (T)ip and (R)ing contacts, and connect all the (S)leeves together.

For what I understand you want:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fllm4r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Using boxes for the connectors because CircuitLab doesn't have a more appropriate symbol.)

If instead of wiring you want to use commonly available audio adapters in a not too messy fashion, I would suggest the following parts:

- 1× TRS to pair of RCA (this can be found in both rigid adapter and Y-cable forms)
- 2× RCA to TRS ([example](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=7241), not a recommendation as I've had very mixed luck with this manufacturer's *adapters* but I don't have a better one)

Less esoteric than the second item would be to use two RCA Y-cables and two pair-of-RCA to TRS cables, but now you have a fairly long string.

Comment: Schematically, yes! That's exactly what I meant. I'm hoping to discover a reasonably simple way of accomplishing the desired result using an off-the-shelf adapter or two.

Comment: @jdmc Ah — I had understood your question as being how to _make_ an adapter instead of stringing together multiple adapters, not that you wanted a minimal set of adapters. I've added a suggestion.

Comment: D_K has lots of dual jacks and single wired plugs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic involved in separating the Left and Right signals from a 3.5 mm (1/8") plug.  The plug has three connections: Left from the tip of the plug, Right from the ring, and Ground (common to Left and Right) on the sleeve.

Ready-made adapator cables should be readily available to go from a 3.5mm stereo plug to two, 1/4" TS plugs, or to two RCA plugs (and probably other combinations.)

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same thing. I have W King D8s that I love. but the lag using bluetooth to watch movies outdoors on a projection screen is horrible.
This will be able to connect 2 speakers from one 3.5 mm stereo jack.
3.5mm Stereo Male to Dual  Mono 3.5mm
[https://www.amazon.com/CablesOnline-3-5mm-Stereo-Audio-Breakout/dp/B0757Q5FB8/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=3.5mm+Stereo+Male+to+Dual+Mono+3.5mm&qid=1619293902&sr=8-6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0757Q5FB8)

Comment: Since these have TS mono connectors, the stereo speakers will need to be capable of mono mode, otherwise they will have one channel silent (since the ring connector on their jack will be connected to ground).